# ng build -prod ERROR: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Generating the production version with @angular/cli command:

ng build --environment prod -prod

**In dev mode work fine**, the source code is:

TS:

```
search() 
{
    this.router.navigate(["search", this.term]);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form (submit)="search(term)"> 
    <input type="text" name="term" [(ngModel)]="term" placeholder="How can I help you today?"/>
    <a (click)="search()"><span class="icon-search"></span></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the 'search' function does not have any parameters or a return type. I know they are inferred but its good practice.

Second you are calling 'search' with a parameter in the event binding 'submit' and that probably is what's causing the issue.

Use '(submit)="search()"'